# Swift - Como alterno automaticamente a image da Imageview

Tags: swift

Possuo algumas imagens e uma ImageView conforme as fotos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de poder alternar a imagem da imageView, trocando de uma para outra a cada 5 segundos automaticamente.

Como poderia fazer isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar transitionWithView:

```
let toImage = UIImage(named:"myname.png")
UIView.transitionWithView(self.imageView,
                          duration:5,
                          options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations: { self.imageView.image = toImage },
                          completion: nil)
```

Exemplo: https://github.com/zazk/Simple-SlideShow-Swift

Você também pode usar essas opções: http://mathewsanders.com/animations-in-swift-part-two

Comment: Bem interessante, obrigado pela dica, mas teria como eu deixar de forma continua? Como um slide mesmo, eu entro no app e na tela inicial aparece o slide intercalando entre as 3 imagens.

Comment: @CristianCotrena Eu só atualizou a resposta

Comment: Queria fazer exatamente da forma que fez, porem com imagens da internet. Pego uma imagem, armazeno em uma UIImage, quando tento colocar a UIImage no animate (onde esta informando as imagens), da erro.

Comment: Também posso estar fazendo errado, mas se me passar um mail, posso te mostrar como tentei fazer

Comment: Ola amigo, consegui fazer da forma que eu queria. Mas tenho uma duvida, quando quero ir para outra ViewController como faço para parar a animação?

Answer (score 1):

Basta agora colocar a logica para trocar para cada imagem.

```
NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: "TrocarImagem", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func TrocarImagem() {
    let imagem = UIImage(named:"imagem01.jpg")
}
```